How should an algorithm work for checking if a compound word can be derived from the base words in a dictionary?
I am trying to think about how to build a cross-language dictionary, where it stores "base" words (like "create", "creation", etc.), and doesn't store derived words (like "created", "creating", "creates", "creations", etc.). Instead of storing the derived words, it stores rules of some sort which specifies how the derived words get created.
One rule might be "if word ends in -p, and we want to add -ing, then do -pping", so "flip" becomes "flipping", etc.. The reason not to store the derived words in the dictionary is there are at least millions of those in English (and only a few hundred thousand "base" words), and in some languages like Turkish, there are a roughly infinite number of possible derived words.
The question is, how should the algorithm roughly work for figuring out if a derived word is in the dictionary?
We could have a Trie for storing the base words, but then what about prefixes and suffixes (ignoring infixes and circumfixes for the moment)? And what about when the combining point changes the end of the preceding chunk, and/or the start of the following chunk (like where "flipping" adds the extra "p" in between, etc.)? I am mainly wondering if I need to do lookahead/lookbehind sorts of things when doing this, or if I can just go through the prefix list, then base word list, then suffix list, in a straightforward manner.
For "flipping", I see "flip" in the base-word trie, and then we encounter "p", no not in the dictionary, so check suffixes. The suffix can insert a "p" if the last fragment ends in "p".... So remember the last character? Or perhaps there are more cases where it's more than just the last character, but a few last characters... So walk through the suffix "last fragments ends with" properties, in reverse (maybe a reverse trie), and we find that our word ends in "p" and we have several suffixes for that (let's assume). Now how to filter down to the correct suffix? We try out all the suffixes perhaps? Try "-p-p-ed", we get "flipped", nope that doesn't match. Try "-p-p-ing", ok that matches, we find a winner.
So it seems so far:

Read fragment left-to-right against trie of fragments.
Upon completion of a fragment, find the next fragments which can start with the next letter.
Build a trie for all the fragments, and another trie for what they can start with.
Reverse read "what they can start with" from the preceding fragment, and if matches, forward read the next fragment.

Something like that? How would you accomplish this?

There is no algorithm that can definitely accomplish this without any extra information because languages are weird. There are several problems with this:

Base words vs. derived words are ambiguous. Why is "creation" considered a based word here, couldn't you argue it was derived from the word "create"? In the rest of this, at least for English, I'm assuming that base words are a non-gerund noun in the singular form, a verb in the present tense, or an adjective ("runny" won't be considered a derived form of the word "run")
There are so many exceptions, at least in the English language. "create" and "created" could be solved for with hard-programmed rules, but that same rule would probably say that "shed" is the past tense for "she". Without knowing exactly whether a word is a noun, verb, or adjective, or what tense, it is impossible to tell if it is a derived word or a base word with any certainty.

So how do you solve this? You find out what the "part of speech" for a word is using tools like nltk. I would recommend that you use wordnet to generate a synset for the word (the set of synonyms), and find their parts of speech for words that have multiple meanings (again, e.g. shed). Then, you remove any words who only function as a gerund, a plural noun or a verb in a non-present tense.
